# Javascript- How to return an array by with a string as parameter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

For a simple function, how can I return an array with a string as a parameter? I want the array to split the string at the spaces so it returns as `[" ", " "]`.

I tried using the split method `split(" ", 2)` but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: What does the string look like to begin with, and what are you expecting, surely not an array with two empty spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arr = str.split(" ");
```

You don't need to add 2 after.

The 2 limit the number of value in the array, if you want to split the string without a max, then take out the 2.

The split will "split" the string with " ", if you want to split with other character, replace the space by what you need.